# Передача айди по радиосигналу по UDP протоколу на python

Tags: python, linux, windows, udp, lan

Пожалуйста, подскажите, где можно поглядеть похожую концепцию написания кода.
Есть блок, который работает по udp протоколу, так же есть кнопка, которая передаёт радиосигнал этому блоку. Блок подключён к компьютеру по lan порту. При нажатии на кнопку, блок должен получить айди адрес кнопки и передать его на компьютер. Где я могу найти что-то подобное, чтоб иметь понятие хотя-бы как это делать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: И все же, уточните -- проблема в -- 1) получением id? 2) отправкой UDP? 3)  IP адрес получателя? 4) что-то еще ...

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, самая простая штука на эту тему - это "Amazon buttons".

Это такие кнопки, который Вы покупаете (по моему, $5 за штуку) и вешаете в разных местах квартиры. Например, рядом со стриральной машиной висит такая кнопка, и когда Вы на неё нажимаете - то это приводит к тому, что происходит заказ стандартной пачки стирального порошка на Амазоне.

Ну, и так далее - одна кнопка - один вид заказа.

Самое хорошее в этой кнопке - что у неё есть "web-ручка", ну, то есть, она подерживает настройку того, что некая лямбда выполнится в амазоновском облаке, когда Вы нажмёте на кнопку.

А так - просто напишите поподробее, пока  непонятно, что такое "блок", почему он подключен к компьютеру именно по LAN, находятся они в однйо сети или вообще просто в интернете, кака OS стоит на компе... короче, напишите поподробнее.

Comment: Подключён по LAN из-за того, что с USB портом будут проблемы с кодом и разными версиями linux, блок- коробка с платой, которая поддерживает UDP протокол обмена данных,так же впаяна микросхема для приёма сигнала с кнопки. Роль этого блока принять сигнал, частота не важна, всё уже откалибровано под нужные частоты, потом отправить компу информацию о том, что такая-то кнопка(её айди), послала сигнал. Делать буду и для linux и для windows, поэтому OS не очень важна сейчас. Интернет и сеть тут вроде роли никакой не играет

Answer (score 0):

Если вопрос "из чего это сделать?" то стоит обратить внимание на кнопки BLE TAG и контроллер ESP32. Контроллер имеет на борту WiFi, Bluetooth/BLE и программируется на Си, Микропитоне и Луа.

Если с микроконтроллерами дела не имел раньше, то можно использовать * Pi (например Orange Pi Zero) - на нем уже есть LAN порт и операционная система с взрослым Питоном.

В этом случае даже паять не надо.

Если немного попаять, то...

Если кнопки стационарны или нужно разложить их на большей площади - то смотри на RF 433 MHZ. Понадобится приёмник RF433MHz , который легко подключить к * Pi.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И готовые кнопки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, но уже всё готово, вопросы остаются по программной части..

Comment: Так я не вижу ни одного вопроса по ПО. Напишите что за блок LAN, что не получается в программе?

Comment: Самому нужно программу написать на python, где можно взять примеры того, как выглядит код?

Comment: так это всё легко, но какое железо у вас и где какая программа будет работать?

Comment: На компьютере Linux, что вы имеете ввиду под 'железо'?

Comment: сигнал с кнопки чем принимается?

Comment: На плате блока есть модуль с приёмником, настроенным под частоту сигнала с кнопки

Comment: какого блока? название у него есть? если он секретный какой, то хотяб схему включения покажи)

Comment: Пришли свою почту, отправлю фотографию

Comment: sa@eri.su но только смысл от фото?)